# Can't change font color in Fireworks CS6

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I've downloaded Poppins from Google Fonts.

Set some text to use Poppins.

Text can't be changed away from black now.

Same for text using a different font in the same file.

Comment: I'm amazed you still have FW running!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by restarting Fireworks CS6